# Pandas map 0/1 data frame entries to column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame in pandas with entries that are either 0 or 1. I would like to reduce this to a single list of strings that are the result from concatentating column names wherever there is a 1.

For a toy example suppose my data frame is

```
   V1 V2 V3
   0  1  1
   1  1  0
   0  0  0
```

I would like to have a final result that looks like

```
"V2,V3"
"V1,V2"
""
```

I had initially tried using something along the lines of

```
my_df.apply(lambda x: colnames[x])
```

thinking it would behave similarly to how numpy handles boolean indices. But, did not achieve what I wanted to do. How should I best accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

convert the dtype of the df to a `bool`, then call [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) and use the boolean mask to mask the columns, you need to pass param `axis=1` to `apply` the column mask row-wise:

```
In [47]:
df.astype(bool).apply(lambda x: ','.join(df.columns[x]), axis=1)

Out[47]:
0    V2,V3
1    V1,V2
2         
dtype: object
```

Your code `my_df.apply(lambda x: colnames[x])` won't work because firstly when calling `apply` on a df without specifying the `axis` will call the lambda on each column in turn, secondly the `1/0` will interpret this as an index value rather than a boolean flag.

Comment: or you might `df.apply(lambda x: '"%s"'%(','.join(df.columns[x==1])), axis=1)`