# Boolean values to column names in one list, dataframe pandas python

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
     A    B    C    D    E
  0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
  1  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
  2  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
  3  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
  4  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
```

The mission is to get a list like this

```
0  B,E
1  C
2  B,C,D
3  A,E
4  D
```

Any ideas, thanks in advance.

Comment: the answer is down :)

Comment: great work agaim, @jezrael

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125954/pandas-map-0-1-data-frame-entries-to-column-names and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38169342/python-pandas-dataframe-return-column-name

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40829103/how-to-efficiently-rearrange-pandas-data-as-follows and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45935143/selecting-all-column-names-where-value-is-greater-than-another-column-in-pandas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` for processing by rows and then compare each row with `1` for index values (because `axis=1` each row is converted to Series with index from columns), which are joined by `,`:

```
s1 = df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.index[x == 1]), axis=1)
print (s1)
0      B,E
1        C
2    B,C,D
3      A,E
4        D
dtype: object
```

Another solution, faster if larger `DataFrame`.

First change format of columns to list:

```
print (['{}, '.format(x) for x in df.columns])
['A, ', 'B, ', 'C, ', 'D, ', 'E, ']
```

Same like:

```
s = np.where(df == 1, ['{}, '.format(x) for x in df.columns], '')
```

because `1` values are casted to `True`s. Compare values of `DataFrame` and for `True`s use custom format of columns names:

```
s = np.where(df, ['{}, '.format(x) for x in df.columns], '')
print (s)
[['' 'B, ' '' '' 'E, ']
 ['' '' 'C, ' '' '']
 ['' 'B, ' 'C, ' 'D, ' '']
 ['A, ' '' '' '' 'E, ']
 ['' '' '' 'D, ' '']]
```

Last join all rows with removing empty values:

```
s1 = pd.Series([''.join(x).strip(', ') for x in s], index=df.index)
print (s1)
0       B, E
1          C
2    B, C, D
3       A, E
4          D
dtype: object
```

EDIT: Old answer another better solution:

```
s1 = df.eq(1).dot(df.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',')
```

Comment: Great answer!, Thanks a lot :)